# How to manage different distribution packages of the same Python package?

Tags: python, distribution, packaging

Is there a way (with [distribute](http://packages.python.org/distribute) or another package) to manage different distributions (meaning different setup.py files) of the same Python package?

Answer (score 1):

You might have a look to [buildout](http://www.buildout.org/docs/tutorial.html). With buildout you can have a single setup.py for a package and have multiple buildout configuration files that specify different ways of building that package with the other packages you want to have in the same distribution (including its version dependencies).

I think with pip freeze, pip bundle you can also achieve something similar but AFAIK only for versions of packages (you can't install and setup an LDAP server for example, but you can do it that in buildout).